# DataGridComboBoxColumn show Foreign Key Table - WPF

Tags: sql, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have an SQL Database, with table Jars and JarTypes. I need to show the data in a DataGrid. I also have to be able to edit the rows. I think a DataGridComboBoxColumn is perfect for the job. How can i populate the ComboBox with JarTypes.Type and put TypeId back into the Jars.TypeId. The tables are stored in DataTables JarsDt and TypeDt

Jars (JarsDt)

- JarId (PK)
- Amount
- TypeId (FK)

JarTypes (TypeDt)

- TypeId (PK)
- Type

### XAML

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="JarDataGrid"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="10,35,2,36.8">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="#"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Binding="{Binding JarId}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mengde"
                                Binding="{Binding Amount}" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="combo"
                                    Header="Glass"
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding TypeId}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Type}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mengde levert"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Binding="{Binding AmountDelivered}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to a list of Jars and the `ItemsSource` property of the `ComboBox` to a list of JarTypes.

You can do this in XAML using a `CollectionViewSource` or in code by directly setting `JarDataGrid.ItemsSource = ListOfJars`.

You need to set the `SelectedValuePath` property of `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

Also `DisplayMemberPath` is a string property, so does not use binding.

In your case it would be:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="combo"
                        Header="Glass"
                        DataContext="{StaticResource jarTypesViewSource}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding TypeId}"
                        SelectedValuePath="TypeId"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Type"/>
```